# Motor running slowly when connected to digital pins, but fine with 5V pins

Tags: arduino-uno, motor

I am trying to connect a Dagu DG01D motor to my Arduino Uno. First I tried connecting the black wire to `GND` and the red wire to digital pin `7`. My code:

```
void setup() {
  pinMode(7, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(7, HIGH);
}

void loop() {
}
```

When I connected the motor, it wouldn't turn, but would rotate a little when turned in one direction. However, when I connected the red wire to `3.3V` or `5V`, the motor turned quickly as expected. **Why didn't writing `HIGH` to pin `7` work?**

I already verified that I can connect and run code on the Arduino by turning on the LED by replacing pin `7` with `13`. I also tried running the same code on a SparkFun RedBoard, with similar results.

Comment: An Arduino pin can only supply an absolute maximum of 40mA of current (20mA is recommended). As Ignacio said, your motor requires around 190mA. Use a transistor, to increase the current capability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> No Load Current: 190mA (250mA MAX)

You're not getting that out of a ATmega328P GPIO. Use a driver instead.